# Android google mapv2 icon from URL

Tags: android, google-maps

Now got problem that I cannot fetch and display custom icon into Google Maps from URL. Regarding Google's example, only icon to be displayed into Google map. But what I want to know is to display icon from URL.

```
private Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(MELBOURNE)
                            .title("Melbourne")
                            .snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
```

and here is my coding.

```
            if(c != null){          
                if(c.moveToFirst()){
                    do {
                        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(c.getString(2)), Double.parseDouble(c.getString(3))))
                        .title(c.getString(0))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp))
                        .snippet(c.getString(1)));
                    } while(c.moveToNext());
                }               
            }
```

Comment: make a http request download the bitmap and use the same.

Comment: can you mention complete example?

Comment: I have answerd here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139515/set-marker-icon-on-google-maps-v2-android-from-url/47471289#47471289](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139515/set-marker-icon-on-google-maps-v2-android-from-url/47471289#47471289)

Comment: Here is the complete solution along with code snippet https://stackoverflow.com/a/61929527/8663316

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can download Bitmap as

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(myurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Used a thread to get the bitmap

Then

```
 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)));
```

From your comments you get `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

So use a thread.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run(){
    URL url ;
    try {
        url = new URL("myurl");
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            source = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(sc)
                    .title("MyHome")
                    .snippet("Bangalore")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(bmp)));
        }
    });
}
});
thread.start();
```

You can't update ui from a background thread. use `runOnUiThread`.

Using asycntask

Make your asycn taks an inner class of your activity. Declare Bitmap as a class variable.

```
 class TheTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>
 {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();

}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    URL url ;
    try {
    url = new URL("myurl");
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
         }
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

super.onPostExecute(result);
    source = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(sc)
    .title("MyHome")
    .snippet("Bangalore")                                                                                     
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin)));                                       
    }
}
```

Comment: @ppshein what error did you get. you need to get the bitmap from the url using a thread.

Comment: URL myurl = new URL("http://www.test.com/about.jpg");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(myurl.openConnection().getInputStream());

Comment: @ppshein what is the error that you get. the code looks fine. post the stacktrace

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 13:08:32.168: E/AndroidRuntime(15982): 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.....LocationActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException


Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-06 
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)

Comment: Use Async task wen u make a request.

Comment: @ppshein that's because you can't do network related operation on the ui thread. You can use a `thread` or `asynctask`. I will edit my post

Comment: seems work but not 100%.Here is my coding and don't know how to integate it.     if(c != null){   
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
         do {
          googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(c.getString(2)), Double.parseDouble(c.getString(3))))
                            .title(c.getString(0))
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp))
                            .snippet(c.getString(1)));
         } while(c.moveToNext());
           }       
       }

Comment: @ppshein why not 100%?. what is c a cursor object? And what is it exactly doing

Comment: @Raghunandan Please check my question. I've mention my coding and don't know how to integrate with your coding.

Comment: @ppshein if you don't know how can i know what your code does. and by the way why did you unaccept to the question asked my post answers. With the code posted is just not enough. please post a new question with relevant details.

Comment: @Raghunandan I want to integrate your coding into my coding. Please let me know how to integrate it?

Comment: @ppshein please post a new thread( a new question) with all the relevant code. the code posted is not enough. Ask a new question with full code if not i certainly the community will help you. Since that's a new topic it will lead to a discussion. so i suggest you open a new thread for your current problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500818/android-google-maps-custom-icon-from-url-stored-in-sqlite

Answer (score 6):

I used [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) to load an image. it is a very good library.

to set marker icon from url is very simple.

```
try {
        Bitmap bmImg = Ion.with(context)
                .load("http://example.com").asBitmap().get();

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmImg)));

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

hope this help

Comment: how change image size or if user add huge image url what will happen have you ever tested?

Comment: @mehmet you can create a new bitmap resized from original bitmap like: Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmImg , bmImg .getWidth()/2, bmImg .getHeight()/2, false);

Comment: well I've solved with Picasso library https://github.com/square/picasso