# Android google maps custom icon from url stored in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps

I'm trying to display custom icon from URL (stored in sqlite) to Google maps v2. Following is my part of coding to display location from sqlite and display at Google Maps. In this coding, I need to add custom icon from sqlite (custom icon variable maybe, "http://www.test.com/test.png") at Google Maps.

```
if(c != null){          
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(c.getString(2)), Double.parseDouble(c.getString(3))))
            .title(c.getString(0))
            .icon(???????)
            .snippet(c.getString(1)));
        } while(c.moveToNext());
    }               
}
```

Please let me know how to solve this one?

Comment: where do you get the url from? from the database? each marker is different?

Comment: yap.. URL is stored in sqlite and each maker is different.

Comment: Store all the urls in an array / arrayList in the global scope by fetching it from db using Cursor class maybe, and use them here as-- Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(myurl.openConnection().getInputStream());

and then .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)));

Comment: @KunalS.Kushwah I've tried already. But cannot get it.

Comment: So basically, your question is you can't GET the url out from the database???

Comment: @KunalS.Kushwah nope, I can get URL out from sqlite but my problem is cannot display such icon from sqlite into google maps.