# How to handle SVG icon by URL and set into the marker icon in andorid programatically

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, svg

I'm working on an app which uses SVG icon by URL. I want to show the icon on the screen. I'm not getting any clear answer. Please show me the right way for using SVG icon by URL. Don't forget to post your answer if you able to find the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android:load svg file from web and show it on image view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215625/androidload-svg-file-from-web-and-show-it-on-image-view)

Comment: @Iffat when I set SVG file on the map icon than what will I do.?

Comment: you need to download the image first in order to set it in the marker. You cannot directly set it from url in the marker.

Comment: maybe this posts can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500229/android-google-mapv2-icon-from-url

Comment: @sofiane Thanks for your suggestion but I already  tried  and it causes an icon size error for different screen sizes mobile